# What is the distinguishing difference between [tag:citation] and [tag:citation-style] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

According to the current descriptions,

> [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) Queries related to citing or referencing published or unpublished sources
>
> [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style) On the syntax and formatting of citations and reference lists according to a particular style guide (e.g., Chicago, MLA, IEEE, APA).

They seem almost similar and it seems like users cannot differentiate their standard use. Many use both in the same time; in such a case the tag [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style) should very well define the question's purpose.

Should they be treated as synonyms, or should I just go through the trouble of re-tagging the questions according to their true descriptions (I don't see any badge for this; [badge:Copy Editor] excludes tag edits)?

Comment: Every time there is a question about tags, I wonder if it's worth any effort caring for them: do really people use tags when searching?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Well... I do.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I do too. Also, questions with your favorite tags are highlighted in the home page: when I browse quickly through the main page, I rely on the fact that the most interesting questions stand out visually. And I believe that they are used in the algorithm to create the list of related questions on the right part of the UI.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm kind of a basic user. Whenever I try to find a specific post through tags, I cannot find it :-( At present I use tags only to hide those about graduate admissions... but it works only for the web interface, not for the app which I use a lot.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The tags are also [used to select related questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l)  which are shown in the sidebar on the right. I guess there are a few reasons why well-maintained tags might be useful. BTW speaking of tags, shouldn't this question be tagged ([meta-tag:tags])?

Comment: @Martin You're right, let's make the edit.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding of the two tags is the following:

- [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) is related to questions about the appropriateness of a citation, e.g.: "Should I cite X if [...]?".
- [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style), instead, is related only to questions about formatting references and citations.

Thus, I wouldn't consider the two as synonyms. Maybe we can improve the description of [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations).

Random examples:

1. [How do I cite a SDS in AMA format?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/76193/20058) This question is tagged with both tags but I think it should be tagged [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style) only.
2. [Is it unethical to cite a paper or book that you have never looked at?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45295/20058) This question is correctly tagged [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations).
3. [How to cite files on a CD-ROM?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75643/20058) This one is tagged [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) but according to my interpretation should be tagged [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style) instead.
4. [How do a cite an article which has been accepted pending revisions, but the revisions aren't accepted yet?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75588/20058) This one again has both tags, but I think that the correct one is [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style).
5. [What does "ad indicem" mean in a citation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75234/20058) This one is tagged [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) but I think it should be tagged [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style) instead.
6. [Citing Math Lesson Plans](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/69237/20058) This one has both tags and actually contain two different questions, one for each tag.

Comment: Before starting to retag any of the examples and others, I'll wait the outcome of this discussion

Comment: I believe that the tag ([tag:citations]) is also used on questions about finding citations. (Some examples can be found [in this search](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcitations%5D+how+find).) The [tag-info](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/citations/info) does not mention this usage of the tag. (Although to me this usage seems reasonable.)