# Should there be tag for ResearchGate?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

A [quick search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=ResearchGate) shows that there are a couple of questions involving ResearchGate. Would it be good to have a [researchgate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/researchgate) tag for such questions?

Of course, one could search for the questions just by the name, but as a tag, it could be prescribed for mail notifications too.

I would like to know the community's views before creating one.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that it seems to be a subset of the existing tag ([tag:social-media]). The [tag-info for this tag](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/social-media/info) says: *Use of social media (e.g. Facebook, ResearchGate, blogs, etc.) by academics to engage with other academics or students and to disseminate and publicize their research."

Comment: @Martin I guess that would make up a good answer. Kindly move it to the answer section. By the way, do you think it would be wise to make a [tag:researchgate] and make it a synonym of [tag:social-media]?

Comment: My comment was intended as a comment. Feel free to expand it to an answer, if you think that it somehow answers your question. (I am not sure it does.) Now I checked that there is also ([tag:facebook]) tag. So it falls under more general tag and still has a separate tag. (I should add that I do not visit academia.SE too often, so I am not very familiar with tags used on this site. Probably it would be better to know the opinion of regular users on this.

Comment: Had to Google this... Thought ResearchGate was some scandal involving bogus statistics.

Answer (score 3):

Around the internet there are several social media and online reference managers that are more of less of interest to academics: Google Scholar, Academia.edu, ResearchGate, Mendeley, LinkedIn, Facebook etc.

At the moment, among them, only Google Scholar and Facebook have specific tags; the others have been divided between the more general tags [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) and [reference-managers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-managers).

Google Scholar is clearly academic-oriented and in many fields it is relatively widespread, but probably cannot be easily classified either as a social media or a reference manager.

Facebook is a popular social media, not specifically geared toward academics, and it's explicitly mentioned in the description of [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media). Moreover, [facebook](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) has, to date, only 6 questions.

ResearchGate, which is explicitly mentioned in the [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) description, has a quite controversial status among the academics, as outlined by several questions and answers in this community (I suspect that many academics use ResearchGate in a passive way: after having signed up, they let their profiles live their autonomous lives.):

1. [ResearchGate: an asset or a waste of time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16870/20058)
2. [Should I send a "cease-and-desist" letter to ResearchGate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24127/20058)
3. [Is it legal to add your publications to ResearchGate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52488/20058)

In addition, at the moment, there are [51 questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=researchgate+is%3Aquestion) containing ResearchGate and [47 questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=linkedin+is%3Aquestion) containing LinkedIn.

After this long preamble, my stance is the following: either we create a tag for each website or we don't, but having specific tags for websites already covered by more general tags looks inconsistent.

Therefore, my suggestion is: keep [google-scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-scholar) (because of 3rd paragraph above), burninate [facebook](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), and don't create ResearchGate.

*Disclaimer*: my suggestion above is biased by the fact that, as [I confessed elsewhere](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/what-is-the-distinguishing-difference-between-tagcitation-and-tagcitation-s#comment10227_3451), I'm not that passionate about tags. Probably, users who use tags extensively, like the OP, might have a completely different opinion.